# Usine JLine2 with SocketInputStream

Tags: java, network-programming, jline

I am currently trying to include the JLine2 library (version 2.13) for the custom telnet implementation, but, I cannot get it to work.

I am creating a ConsoleReader with:

```
ConsoleReader reader = new ConsoleReader("Telnet", socket.getInputStream(), 
    socket.getOutputStream(), new DefaultTerminal2(TerminalFactory.get()), "UTF-8");
```

When I press the up arrow to move back through the history, character ^[[A is printed (same happens with down arrow, only ^[[B), but when I press 'Enter' the the selected command from the history is properly executed.

Could someone point me to which direction should I go, in order to have the command history properly displayed while pressing arrows?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue, more than that, it looks like the telent console cannot print the `\n` correct.